# Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"

Tags: html, c#-4.0

Am exporting html content(user typed content-paragraph-hmtl page) to MS-word(doc). When i exporting content to word using C# Click event. Its work fine. But it has some blue border around the content. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cdsF.png)

```
 Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Candidatename + "_" + filename + ".doc");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
    tb = new Table();
    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    tr1.Attributes.Add("style", "border: 0px");
    tb.Attributes.Add("style", "border: 0px");
    cell1.Attributes.Add("style", "border: 0px");
    cell1.Text = Convert.ToString(str);
    tr1.Cells.Add(cell1);
    tb.Rows.Add(tr1);


    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    tb.RenderControl(hw);
```

variable "str" get the value from sql server(Dynamic data which was typed by the user in text area control .

Answer (score 0):

It's a table, where contents are in.

If you Click on Layout / View Gridlines, wich are activated, you'll deactivate them and these lines dissapear.
When you print that document, these lines will not be printed